# pandas rolling window regression ols precision

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statsmodels

I see that pandas rolling window multiple regression does not give very precise results. The betas are all a bit off because I suppose because it's trying to run fast? Is there a way to force it to give more accurate results? (I tested results against Excel)

Here is my sample code

```
testData = pd.DataFrame({'x0': (105.2827928,105.2865254,105.2860275,105.2868111,105.2867191,105.2941308,105.3040566,105.3175178,105.3249605,105.3319957,105.3343568,105.335711,105.3370348,105.3475904,105.3521867,105.354053,105.3460503,105.3524061,105.3495786,105.337429),
    'x1': (11084.46645,11085.25243,11085.14758,11085.31259,11085.29323,11086.85397,11088.94433,11091.77955,11093.34731,11094.82933,11095.32673,11095.61202,11095.8909,11098.11479,11099.08324,11099.47649,11097.79032,11099.12947,11098.53371,11095.97394),
    'y': (0.523565383,0.533596935,0.5284088,0.533871668,0.534186651,0.523456406,0.522441767,0.515393324,0.518692219,0.518244902,0.494972089,0.491874655,0.4812694,0.459134135,0.452782801,0.460237668,0.46330172,0.425602082,0.438262734,0.414538997)})

model = pd.ols(y=testData.y,x=testData[['x0','x1']],window=10)
```

I have also created an Excel spreadsheet that shows the Excel betas. http://speedy.sh/nhHwy/pandasOlsIssue.xlsx

Comment: In what way are your results not precise?

Comment: Closely check the output of both excel and pandas and make sure you are comparing apples to apples.  I.e. check number of observations, number of variables (is a constant automatically added in each case?), etc.  Also make sure neither one is automatically using some sort of robust standard errors or bootstrapping, etc.

Comment: Also, make sure that regular OLS gives the same answers before moving on to rolling.

Comment: regular (non rolling) OLS in pandas gives the exact same results as Excel. Rolling give approximately the same result (generally close, but not always).

Comment: You'll just have to inspect the output, probably 'window' is not defined the same for each one.  For example, are the first 9 rows defined as a window with 9 rows or as missing?

Comment: Actually I know rolling windows OLS works exactly sometimes. I got rolling window OLS to match exactly with Excel for a simple regression. I even got it to work for a multiple regression on a different dataset. It just doesn't work exactly with my example numbers above.

Comment: Hmm... that does seem strange then.  You might try doing it in statsmodels or scipy (and maybe add those tags to your question to make sure those folks see your question).  Also, it might help to show some results from both excel and pandas so folks know exactly what is different.

Comment: I have created an Excel sheet that shows the problem exactly. http://speedy.sh/nhHwy/pandasOlsIssue.xlsx